# Make enter key execute controller method

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, commandbutton, inputtext

I have an inputText being used as a search bar along with a commandButton that when pushed executes the search method in my controller. What I would like to add is that when the user pushes the enter key, it will execute the search method as well.

```
<apex:inputText id="searchBar" value="{!nameSearch}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" status="statusId"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the enter function that I went with.

```
<script>
    function enterPress(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            if(e.preventDefault){ 
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else{
                e.returnValue=false;
            }
            validate();
        }        
    }
    function validate(){
        var inp = document.getElementById('{!$Component.EntireRelationshipWidget.headerForWidget.searchAndClearButtons.searchBarForm.searchBar}').value;
        if(inp.length < 3){
            alert('Please enter at least 3 characters to search.');
            return false;
        }
        searchFunction();
        return true;
    }
</script>
<apex:inputText id="searchBar" value="{!nameSearch}" onkeypress="enterPress(event)"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Search" rerender="EntireRelationshipWidget" status="statusId" onclick="return validate();"/>
<apex:actionFunction action="{!search}" name="searchFunction" />
```